# Standard error on elements in covariance matrix?

Tags: normal-distribution, sample-size, covariance, standard-error, uncertainty

I have multiple random (gaussian) variables.

Just as one can calculate the standard error on the mean, I expect to be able to calculate standard error on the variances and standard error on the covariances.

How to do this?

Comment: by "error" do you mean "standard error" ?

Comment: Yes I mean standard error